# Why are the byte representations for extended ASCII characters from bytes() different from chr()?

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, ascii

(I am working in python)

Suppose I have this list of integers

```
a = [170, 140, 139, 180, 225, 200]
```

and I want to find the raw byte representation of the ASCII character each integer is mapped to. Since these are all greater than 127, they fall in the Extended ASCII set. I was originally using the chr() method in python to get the character and then encode() to get the raw byte representation.

```
a_bytes = [chr(decimal).encode() for decimal in a]
```

Using this method, I saw that for numbers greater than 127, the corresponding ASCII character is represented by 2 bytes.

```
[b'\xc2\xaa', b'\xc2\x8c', b'\xc2\x8b', b'\xc2\xb4', b'\xc3\xa1', b'\xc3\x88']
```

But when I used the bytes() method, it appears that each character had one byte.

```
a_bytes2 = bytes(a)
>>> b'\xaa\x8c\x8b\xb4\xe1\xc8'
```

So why is it different when I use chr().encode() versus bytes()?

Comment: If you don't specify an encoding, `encode()` will use UTF-8, which will use two bytes for these characters.  Try `encode('latin-1')`.

Comment: Python  doesn't use any of the several dozen "extended ASCII" character sets. It uses Unicode. The `chr()` function gives you the character corresponding to a Unicode codepoint. If you call `encode()`  on a character with a codepoint above 127, you will get the default encoding, which is UTF-8. Codepoints in the range 128-255 can have a representation of more than one byte in UTF-8. If you want to see a one-byte representation, encode the codepoint using  a charmap encoding such as  Windows-1252, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Extended ASCII".  ASCII is defined as bytes (and code points) in the range 0-127. Most standard single-byte code pages (which are used to convert from bytes to code points) use ASCII for bytes 0-127 and then map 128-255 to whatever is convenient for the code page.  Russian code pages map those bytes to Cyrillic code points for example.

In your example, `.encode()` defaults to the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding which maps the code points 0-127 to ASCII and follows multibyte encoding rules for any code point above 128.  `chr()` converts an integer to its corresponding, fixed Unicode code point.

So you have to choose an appropriate encoding to see what a byte in that encoding represents as a character.  As you can see below, it varies:

```
>>> a = [170, 140, 139, 180, 225, 200]
>>> ''.join(chr(x) for x in a)  # Unicode code points
'ª\x8c\x8b´áÈ'
>>> bytes(a).decode('latin1')   # ISO-8859-1, also matches first 256 Unicode code points.
'ª\x8c\x8b´áÈ'
>>> bytes(a).decode('cp1252')   # USA and Western Europe
'ªŒ‹´áÈ'
>>> bytes(a).decode('cp1251')   # Russian, Serbian, Bulgarian, ...
'ЄЊ‹ґбИ'
>>> bytes(a).decode('cp1250')   # Central and Eastern Europe
'ŞŚ‹´áČ'
>>> bytes(a).decode('ascii')  # these bytes aren't defined for ASCII
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Also, when displaying bytes the Python default is to display printable ASCII characters as characters and anything else (unprintable control characters and >127 values) as escape codes:

```
>>> bytes([0,1,2,97,98,99,49,50,51,170,140,139,180,225,200])
b'\x00\x01\x02abc123\xaa\x8c\x8b\xb4\xe1\xc8'
```